# background process outputs to the console

Tags: bash

Suppose `test.sh` is a bash script that is empty or contains only `exit 0`.  When the script is backgrounded, what is the significance of the `1` and `16320` printed to the console?

```
b@sam:~/Documents/bashscripts$ ./test.sh &
[1] 16320
b@sam:~/Documents/bashscripts$ 
[1]+  Done                    ./test.sh
b@sam:~/Documents/bashscripts$
```

Then if user hits ENTER at the command prompt, as illustrated above, another line appears and it shows this

`[1]+  Done      ./test.sh`

What is the significance of the `1` digit and the `+` symbol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[1]` is the background job number, used for shell builtin commands like `fg` and `bg` which manage multiple tasks running in the same shell. `jobs` lists the current jobs.

`16320` is the process ID number of the task, useful if you want to `kill` it or similar.

`[1]+ Done` indicates the background process has exited. Since you requested to run it in the background with `./test.sh &`, it didn't wait for it to finish before giving you a fresh prompt (even though it finished almost immediately). The shell therefore notifies you the next time it gives you a prompt.

The `+` indicates the current (most recent) job, if you have multiple jobs running.

See the [bash manual](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/features_5.html) for more information.